# Not able to display services list in terminal: Docker

Tags: docker

Going through Part 3 tutorial of Docker's [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/).

I was able to run the load balanced app with 5 instances using the below command

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
top-level network "webnet" is ignored
service "web": network "webnet" is ignored
Waiting for the stack to be stable and running...
web: Ready      [pod status: 5/5 ready, 0/5 pending, 0/5 failed]
```

But, when I try to list the services with command `docker service ls`  it *does not* show any data.

```
$ docker service ls
ID   NAME   MODE   REPLICAS   IMAGE   PORTS
```

Am I doing something wrong here. Could anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Kubernetes instead of Swarm as the orchestrator. In the current implementation, you can only get the services for a specific stack, not list all services.

```
docker stack services getstartedlab
```

Perhaps you didn't mean to use Kubernetes as the stack orchestrator? You can disable it by going the Docker menu → Preferences… → Kubernetes, and unchecking “Enable Kubernetes”.

Comment: That explains. It looks like the Tutorial Docs needs to be updated.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, the tutorial docs you're following are for Swarm as the orchestrator. You have Kubernetes set as the orchestrator, hence the difference. The docs are correct for Swarm.